# Flash messages display and sometimes they don't

Tags: laravel, vue.js, flash-message

I'm using a `spatie/laravel-flash` for displaying some flash messages. It works when I use simple HTML forms, but when I use Vue.js templates, the message doesn't show. (and sometimes they don't) after submitting the form and go to the next request.

**main layout**

```php
<div class="col-lg-12 mb-2">
    @include('layouts.partials.flash_message')
</div>
<section class="py-5">
    @yield('content')
</section>
```

**layouts.partials.flash_message**

```php
@if(flash()->message)
    <div class="{{ flash()->class }} alert-dismissible" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close close-white" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
        {{ flash()->message }}
    </div>
@endif
```

**create.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.main_layout')
@section('content')   
    <create-school> </create-school>
@endsection
```

**Vue.js template store() method**

```
store()
{
    axios.post('/master/schools', {
        name: this.name,
    }.then((response) => {
        this.name = ''
    }));
}
```

**Laravel store method**

```php
<?php

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $school = School::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
    ]);

    flash('success message', 'alert alert-success');

    return back();
}
```

Comment: Sending data through AJAX is not the same as submitting a basic HTML form. Standard HTML forms send a browser request that causes a new page load, but the point of AJAX is to send and receive data without needing to reload the page. The blade templates that print the flash message are only rendered on page load, so they will not show up for AJAX requests.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using ajax to store your data, you will need to provide the message as a response in that request. So basically the `store` method on your controller would look like

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $school = School::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
    ]);

    return response($school, 201);
}
```

201 is the HTTP code to indicate a resource was created, and the by the RFC you should return the resource in the response.

In your Vue file, the `store` method would then be

```
store()
{
    axios.post('/master/schools', {
        name: this.name,
    }.then((response) => {
        this.name = ''
        // Modify your DOM or alert the user
        alert('Resource created')
    }));
}
```

As a recomendation, you should aways validate user input before storing.

Comment: You're welcome. If you find my answer was of some help to you, please upvote it. And if it solves the problem presented, do not hesitate to mark the question as answered.